# How to get city boundaries of Europe?

Tags: extract, administrative-boundaries, europe, city

I am looking for an up-to-date **communes administrative boundraries** (LAU) of several countries in Europe (France + adjacent countries). I need it to be quite precise (less than 5m), since I intend to use it to retrieve commune names from a point (bus stop). I was thinking about OpenStreetMap and Overpass Turbo, but the coverage seems to be too wide to be processed, even country by country, here is one of my resquest :

```
[out:xml][timeout:600]; (
  area['admin_level'='2']['name'='France'];
  rel['boundary'='administrative']['admin_level'='8'](area);
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

I also found

- [[something interesting]](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/communes#communes13) on the [eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/home) website, but it is from 2013 ...
- [[Official LAU]](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/lau), but it not precise enough for my needs
- [[GDAM data]](https://www.gadm.org/download_country_v3.html), but again, not precise enough

Comment: What is your definition of "city"? Population? Administrative specifics ("city status", probably varying vastly between countries)? Are you interested in administrative borders or the actual urbanized area? Your Eurostat link refers to communes, not cities. If that's what you need, then LAU 2 units might help you a lot.

Comment: See answers here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182530/seeking-urban-area-shapefiles-for-france-germany-and-belgium which might be of use, although I acknowledge the datasets are some years old.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Probably Quick OSM could be a solution for you. It's a QGIS plugin. You can easily do Overpass Turbo requests with it from within QGIS and you have several options to choose from (also the Timeout time for big requests).

Comment: Perhaps there is some way to download data from the Inspire dataportal of France https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/donnees/limites-administratives

Answer (score 2):

You have many global datasets on this site:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

You can try the urban areas dataset.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it doesn't seems to host what I need, I am looking for administrative boundaries, smaller than countries (admin 0)

Comment: have you tried the "Admin 0 - Details" dataset on the same link at the top?

Comment: Yes, but they all seems to be detailing counties border, not communes/cities

Comment: On the website http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata, you can download the administrative boundaries of each country in the world (level 1 to 5 depending on the country). 
It's a little reversive, but it's not very long. Then you can merge the boundaries of the different layers under QGIS.